# How to call Chrome speech API using only keyboard?

Tags: google-chrome, speech-recognition

Google Chrome's speech API is awesome!So, I'd like to use it by keyboard.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can't. You *have* to click the microphone button to activate it.

Looking at Chromium's test cases for testing speech input, even [their testing script](http://www.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/LayoutTests/fast/speech/speech-input-scripting.html&exact_package=chromium&q=testSetAttributeAndClick&ct=rc&cd=9) sends a command to move the mouse cursor over the button, and then clicks it:

Answer (score 1):

You can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> (period) but it will work if your input element already in focus.

Comment: Sorry my bad, its Ctrl-Shift-. (period)